# How to use the Watson Assistant "listLogs" API function for a versioned workspace?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

How can I use the [Watson Assistant "listLogs" API Function](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant#list-log-events-in-a-workspace) to list the user conversations from a specific assistant ? We have one skill linked to three assistants for our environments (DEV/TEST/PROD), and I want to retrieve the conversations from PROD assistant only. What filters do I have to use ?

What I already tried:

- When using the listLogs function with just the "workspace_id" as parameter, it is returning just an empty list.
- When using the listAllLogs function with a filter parameter (*language::de,workspace_id::my-workspace-id*), the resulting list is empty as well
- When using the listAllLogs function with another filter parameter (*language::de,meta.conversation.assistant_and_skill_reference::"my-assistant-id:main+skill"*), again an empty list is returned

As the skill is used in live chatbot, there are thousands of logged conversations, all visible in the Analytics tab of the Watson Assistant console, so the data is definitely there.

UPDATE: This is the out from the [Watson Conversation Tool](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool), it's empty
[image]

Comment: The logs API is v1, before Assistants were introduced. How do you invoke that API and are you using the workspace or skill ID?

Comment: I'm looking up the workspace id by View API Details / Workspace ID. I am using the Node.JS package watson-developer-cloud/assistant/V1, you can see the invocation code in my Github project: https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-watson/blob/feature/BOT-652-core-watson-intent-importer-aus-/src/watsonintents.js#L106

Comment: I have used the Python SDK before and succeeded in downloading the logs: https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool/blob/master/wctool.py#L170

Comment: I know this tool, and it worked until we switched from the workspace model to the Assistant/Skill model in Watson (by the way, thanks for this great tool, it helped us a lot). Not all calls return an empty log list (although lot's of data is visible in the Watson console).

Comment: I would recommend to open a support case and ask. I would have expected logs to show up.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the information from IBM Support that this is currently not possible.